# IntelliJ switching between JBOSS_HOME

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss

Using intelliJ 15 Ultimate on MAC Yosemite.
I have two Jboss installation, jboss-eap-6.4 and wildfly-10.1.0.Final.
Depending on what project I am working on I need the "Run/Debug Configuration" to choose the correct JBOSS_HOME.

My bash_profile :

```
export JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4
```

I also added convenience way to change in the terminal

```
alias setEAP='JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4'
alias setWILDFLY='export JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/wildfly-10.1.0.Final'
```

In Intellij I have : 
[image]
Every time I run one of the Run/Debug it chooses the JBOSS_HOME set in bash_profile.

```
/usr/local/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/standalone.sh

WARNING:  JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.

JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/jboss-eap-6.4
```

I tried to create an External Tool where I export JBOSS_HOME, but this does not work. Anyway I can switch between JBOSS installation ? This could also be applicable to JAVA_HOME

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create scripts, just go to the Startup/Connection tab and add the value to the list of environment variables.

[image]